# Set specific font for Xamarin Android and iOS app

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Building apps in VS 2015 Xamarin and wondering if and how I can set the font to Segoe? I looked at font family in the designer, but not sure how that works exactly. Could someone point me in the right direction? Is this pretty direct? Can you use custom fonts?

Thanks much.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/

Comment: Segoe is a Microsoft font, which raises license issues, see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/segoe-ui-font-licensing